# CMD to C# translating

Tags: c#, cmd

Can someone help me to translate this .cmd to c#

```
@echo off

title Windows Activation check by dsoft

cscript C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dli | FIND "259200" >NUL
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%' EQU '0' (
echo Windows is already activated.
) ELSE (
echo Windows is not activated, Try later again.
)
pause
```

Comment: short answer: no... you should try it yourself

Comment: "Questions asking for code must show a minimal understanding of the problem". Perhaps you can show us your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start a process for cscript and provide the vbs file und Find command as arguments. The result can be checked by the exitcode:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = " C:\\Windows\\system32\\slmgr.vbs /dli | FIND \"259200\" >NUL";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        if (p.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Windows is already acivated.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Windows is not activated, Try later again.");
        }
```